# How do I convert a formatted date into a unix timestamp?

Tags: php

How can I convert a date in the following format to a unix timestamp?

```
Thu, 26 Dec 2013 17:53:05 +0100
```

Thanks, Regards !

Comment: Are you trying to convert from the number to a date, or from a date to the number?

Comment: right from date to number

Comment: Before your edit, the numbers in your question looked like timestamps multiplied by 1000. Now you just want normal Unix timestamps?

Comment: Yes because the script get the data of date from this number and my script save from date(r) in db save the date as this : Thu, 26 Dec 2013 17:53:05 +0100 but need get unix timestamp , thank´s

Comment: You need to clarify the question. Unix timestamps are in seconds, but you want milliseconds.

Comment: Why edit my question ? the question it´s about hihghcharsts and his microtome unis timestam all my orginal questions it´s delete and put only onle line when i don´t put that , it´s incredible , the question havehis reason because this microtome need works with this framework no only the unix timestamp incredible this moderation delete all and put the question as he want , incredible , this website it´s nazi website

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime):

For example,

```
echo(strtotime("Thu, 26 Dec 2013 17:53:05 +0100"));
```

will output

```
1388076785
```

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) will give you a unix timestamp from a date string, provided it's in a valid format.

Comment: strtotime(date("r"))*1000 , it´s tight ?

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

***Verbose version (oop / robust):***

```php
$dateString = 'Thu, 26 Dec 2013 17:53:05 +0100';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    DateTime::RSS, 
    $dateString,
    new DateTimeZone('UTC')
);

echo $date->getTimestamp().PHP_EOL  // 1388076785
    .$date->format('r').PHP_EOL;    // Thu, 26 Dec 2013 17:53:05 +0100
```

[**: demo**](http://ideone.com/1bzjKZ)